# How to list source files from within React app

Tags: reactjs

I'm putting together a simple portfolio site in React, where each page is a rendered Markdown file (using [ReactMarkdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-markdown)). Each Markdown file is stored in `src/pages/*.md`

I'm trying to figure out how to list the contents of `src/pages/` so that I can dynamically create a list of pages the user can visit, but I'm not really sure how to do this

I tried using the `fs` module, but got errors saying `readdir()` wasn't defined

Is `fs` the correct approach? Or is there a more appropriate way to list the files?

**NOTE:** The location of the files is arbitrary. If it's easier to read from `public/` that's fine too

Comment: fs is a node module and does not work in browsers

Comment: k that's what i was thinking, so without `fs`, is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: try `next.js` :) it has already has exactly what you want. But you need to run a node server